# How to update a d3 visualization without redrawing every frame?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am using d3 to create a waveform visualization. I have it looking great, but in my efforts to design this waveform I have paid no attention to doing it an optimized way; I just was trying to get it to work.

```
setInterval(function() {
  if (refresh) waveform();
  if (palette_refresh) {
    palette_refresh = false;
    updateColorPalette();
  }
}, options.refresh_rate);

function waveform() {
  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fd);
  document.getElementById('wf_box').innerHTML = "";

  var data = ... irrelevant implementation details ...

  var chart = d3.select("#wf_box").append("svg")
    .attr("class", "chart")
    .attr("width", "" + percent_offset + "%")
    .attr("style", "padding-left:" + (100 - percent_offset) + "%;")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + Math.max(w * data.length, 0) + " " + Math.max(h, 0));

  chart.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      var x_offset = x(i) - Math.max(w * max / 900 - 0.25, 0.1) / 2;
      return x_offset;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
      var height = y(d * options.bar_height) / h;
      return h - Math.pow(Math.max(height, 0.01), 1.5);
    })
    .attr("width", function(d) {
      return '1px';
    })
    .attr("height", function(d, i) {
      var height = y(d * options.bar_height) / h;
      return Math.pow(Math.max(height, 0.01), 1.5) + options.bar_y_offset;
    });
}
```

As you can see, I am calling the waveform function repeatedly using options.refresh_rate as my speed. I would imagine that there is a more efficient way of updating the data used in my waveform than deleting the waveform from the DOM and redrawing it every frame. Does anybody have any insight to how I can accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a working example?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the enter/exit/update-pattern in d3 https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218 and see if that can give you a hint.